# Debugging SQL join each statement

Tags: join, google-bigquery

I was wondering how to debug an SQL `JOIN EACH` statement. Please provide some useful techniques, referring to the code below:

```
SELECT TAT.*,CLAIM.MASC_NM,
      CLAIM.COUNTRY,CLAIM.CARRIER_MODEL 
      FROM X TAT JOIN  EACH
     (
      (SELECT CLAIM_NUM, MASC_NM AS MASC_NM, COUNTRY, 
       CARRIER_MODEL FROM Y CLAIMS WHERE UPLOAD_DT>='2014-01-01' 
       GROUP  BY CLAIM_NUM, MASC_NM, COUNTRY, CARRIER_MODEL) CLAIM
       LEFT JOIN Z 
        ON TAT.CLAIM_NUM=CLAIM.CLAIM_NUM
```

Comment: Not familiar with `JOIN EACH` - what database system are you using? (E.g. [tag:sql-server], [tag:oracle], [tag:mysql], etc)

Comment: i think this is whats called "FULL JOIN" in MS SQL Server

Comment: JOIN EACH, isn't that Google BigQuery? (A JOIN for huge tables?)

Comment: `JOIN EACH` in BigQuery behaves just like `JOIN` - no mysteries here. EACH is just a "shuffling" hint for the engine to process joins between giant tables. However the question doesn't give enough context on what kind of debugging or results they are expecting.

Comment: Can you provide some details about the error(s) and/or unexpected results you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

for starter, make sure each join statement has an "On" Statement